# Polynomials of degree $\ge2$ whose images partition $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, reference-request

I'm looking for a set of polynomials $S\subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that 
$$f(\mathbb{Z})\cap g(\mathbb{Z})\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$$
for all $f\neq g\in S$ and such that
$$\bigcup_{f\in S}f(\mathbb{Z})\supset \mathbb{N}.$$
Now, this is pretty easy. Simply take $\{X\}\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. However, I'm imposing the extra condition that 
$$\min\{\deg f:f\in S\}\ge 2.$$

**Question** does such a set of polynomials exist?

---

It's clear that such a set of polynomials must be infinite, but that's about as far as I got. Maybe one could generate these polynomials recursively, by taking the first few and then finding a polynomial which attains the lowest value not yet covered, while never obtaining a value already obtained by one of the others, but I fail to see how that would work exactly.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  Take any $f\in \mathbb Z$ for which $f(n)\in \mathbb N$ for some integer $N$.  Then take $f=g$ in your first equality.     Clearly $f(\mathbb Z)\cap f(\mathbb Z)\cap \mathbb N$ at least contains $f(n)$, no?

Comment: @lulu My mistake. I needed $f\neq g$

Comment: Ok....but then how is $S=\{X\}$ an example?

Comment: @lulu well, the condition holds for all pairs of distinct polynomials in $S$, doesn't it?

Comment: @lulu Well, $3$ is a natural number, but as far as I know, not a square of an integer. Notice the direction of the set inclusion ($\supset$ instead of the usual $\subset$)

Comment: Got it. $\quad $

Comment: If $S$ is required to be finite, what happens?  Does such a set $S$ exist?  (I am very certain that the answer to this version of the problem is a big ***no*** due to the arbitrarily large gaps between two consecutive values of $f(\mathbb{Z})$ for any quadratic $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow me to assume that $0$ is not a natural number. If you want it to be, then we can probably fix this, but for now let's exclude it. Let $SF\subset\mathbb{N}$ be the set of square-free natural numbers. Consider the set of polynomials $P=\{nx^2|n\in SF\}$. I claim that these polynomials partition $\mathbb{N}$ in the way you want.

See the following post for the existence and uniqueness of factorizations of natural numbers into square and square-free parts: [Show that every $n$ can be written uniquely in the  form $n = ab$, with $a$ square-free and $b$ a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21282/show-that-every-n-can-be-written-uniquely-in-the-form-n-ab-with-a-squa)

Now, it is clear by the existence part that $\bigcup f(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{N}$ for the polynomials $f\in P$. The uniqueness part guarantees us that the images of two different polynomials do not overlap.

EDIT: As Exodd noted below in a comment, you may simply subtract 1 from every polynomial in $P$ in order to fix the issue with $0$.

Comment: subtract -1 to every polynomial to fix $0$

Comment: Oh yea. Good call, lol.

Answer (score 5):

It is kind of a cheat, but since you are only requiring natural numbers, what about defining
$$f_n(x) := -(n+1)x^2 +n$$
and and using the set $S := \{f_n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$? As $f_n(x) < 0$ for all $x \neq 0$, we have$f_n(\mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{N} = \{n\}$, so your conditions are trivially fulfilled.